# React client and Javascript server. Socket.io server error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I'm following a tutorial to learn React by building a PVP chess game. The game logic is written, and I'm currently working on using websockets (socket.io) to allow players to join a game and communicate moves.

I'm getting a server error detailed in the browser console that I need help solving, specifically:

```
`Websocket connection error:  Error: server error
    onPacket socket.js:335
    node_modules bundle.js:46361
    onPacket transport.js:98
    callback polling.js:116
    onData polling.js:119
    node_modules bundle.js:46361
    onLoad polling.js:352
    onreadystatechange polling.js:288`
```

which is being caught through this code:

```
socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
        console.log('Websocket connection error: ', error)
    })
```

I'm at a loss as to what to try.

The following is the server side code (index.js):

```
   const http = require('http');
   const socketio = require('socket.io');
   const express = require('express');
   const { addPlayer, game, removePlayer } = require('./game');
   const cors = require('cors');

   const app = express();

   app.use(cors());
   app.use(express.json());
   app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send({ status: 'healthy' }));
   const server = http.createServer(app);
   const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

   const io = socketio(server);


server.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server running on port ' + PORT));
 io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("connections")
    socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
        console.log(error)
     });
    socket.on('join', ({ name, gameID }, callback) => {
        // create player from socket details
        const { error, player, opponent } = addPlayer({
            gameID,
            name,
            playerID: socket.id,
        });
        console.log(player)
        if (error) {
            return callback({ error })
        }

        socket.join(gameID);
        callback({ colour: player.colour });

        // send welcome message to player1, and also send the opponent player's data
        socket.emit('welcome', {
            message: `Hello ${player.name},  Welcome to the game`,
            opponent,
        });

        // Tell player2 that player1 has joined the game.
        socket.broadcast.to(player.gameID).emit('opponentJoin', {
            message: `${player.name} has joined the game. `,
            opponent: player
        });
    
        // if game  2 players, it's ready to go.
        if (game(gameID).length >= 2){
            const white = game(gameID).find((player) => player.colour === 'w');
            io.to(gameID).emit('message', {
                message: `Let's start the game. White (${white.name}) goes first`,
            });
        }
    });

    // send move 
    socket.on('move', ({ from, to, gameID }) => {
        socket.broadcast.to(gameID).emit('opponentMove', { from, to });
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        const player = removePlayer(socket.id);

        if (player) {
            io.to(player.game).emit('message', {
                message: `${player.name} has left the game.`,
            });
            socket.broadcast.to(player.game).emit('opponentLeft');
        }
    });

});
```

and the client side code directly related to the socket:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

 // listening for events from the server
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(socket.active)
        socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
            console.log('Websocket connection error: ', error)
        })
        socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log(socket)
        console.log('Socket connected');
        socket.emessageit('join', { name: 'Frank', gameID: '20' }, ({ error, color }) => {
            console.log({ color });
        });
        socket.on('Welcome', ({ message, opponent }) => {
            console.log({ message, opponent });
        });
        socket.on('opponentJoin', ({ message, opponent }) => {
            console.log({ message, opponent });
        });

        socket.on('opponentMove', ({ from, to }) => {
            chess.move({ from, to });
            setFen(chess.fen());
        });
    })

}, [chess]);
```

I thought it could be a CORS issue at first, but the initial connection seems to be fine as console.log(socket.active) returns true, and I'm not getting any cors errors in the browser console.

If it's helpful, the link to the tutorial: [https://stack-chess-tutorial.netlify.app/docs/11-socket.io-server](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I explicitly added 'websocket' to the transports list option for the socket like so:

```
const socket = io('localhost:5000', {
    transports: ['websocket'] 
});
```

this gave more detail to the error I received within the console:
Websocket connection error:  Error: It seems you are trying to reach a       Socket.IO server in                 v2.x with a v3.x client, but they are not compatible (more information here: https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/)

I upgraded the socket version used by the server to 3.x, which solved the error.